# How to customize the tab bar of a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have an iPad project using UITabBarController. I want to customize tab bar which shows up in the bottom. I want to create tabs of equal length, which is not a default case. If you create 3 tabs, the middle one is given a little space and the other two taking up lot of space. How to make these three tabs of equal length?

Comment: The tabs are auto-sized to fit, so an easy way to address this is to pad out the name of the middle tab instead of calling it "m" call it "    m    ".

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JBTabBarConroller](https://github.com/jinthagerman/JBTabBarController). It gives you a lot of control over the tab bar that gets displayed. You can customize it easily to make the distances be equal.